# Canvas rectangle fill with colour

Tags: javascript, .net, css, html5-canvas

I was trying to create a rectangle which within html 5 canvas for which i can provide value from min to max. For this i am thinking to create a gradient variable like

```
  defaultGradient: {
        0.4: 'blue',
        0.6: 'cyan',
        0.7: 'lime',
        0.8: 'yellow',
        1.0: 'red'
    }
```

For instance user enters value 50 so the application should select mid of blue and Cyan and fill the rectangle. help appreciated. I have gone through with different links of SO but didn't worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can work with RGB. For example cyan has the RGB (r1, g1, b1) ...

> cyan: rgb(r1, g1, b1)
>
> blue: rgb(r2, g2, b2)

When user enters 50 you need to calculate color between these:

```
  resultColor = rgb((r1+r2)/2 , (g1+g2)/2, (b1+b2)/2)
```

If user enters 41:

```
 resultColor = rgb(((19 * r1)+r2)/20 , ((19*g1)+g2)/20, ((19*b1)+b2)/20)
```